# Is there a simple way to convert a list to a column dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I have a list of POSIXct (timestamps) data that I want to put in a single-column data frame. Using the as.data.frame function gives me instead each timestamp in a single columns, so that the dataframe is 1 x n instead of n x 1. I cannot convert back to a matrix first or use the t() function as this will force the values back into a numeric form. Is there a way to directly go from the list to the dataframe?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the list is called `list_data` you can try -

```
data <- data.frame(timestamp = do.call(c, list_data))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
data <- tibble(timestamp = invoke(c, list_data))
```